# $G$ is supersolvable if the maximal subgroups of Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

$G$ is supersolvable if the maximal subgroups of its Sylow subgroups are normal in $G$. Then $G'$ is nilpotent. If $P$ is a non-normal Sylow subgroup of $G$, then why is $P$ not contained in $G'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P \subseteq G'$, then, since $G'$ is nilpotent, $P \unlhd G'$ and hence $P \text{ char } G' \unlhd G$, so then $P \unlhd G$.